# Bisection method to $f(x) = \cos(x) - xe^{x}= 0$ .

Tags: numerical-methods, bisection

I was doing an example of  Bisection method  applied to $f(x) = \cos(x) - xe^{x}= 0$,[image]

I did all correctly upto 4th step , but after that i don't understand how it is considering the interval of $(0.5,0531)$ as i am getting it to be $(0.562,0.625)$
as $f(0.562)>0$ and $f(0.625)<0$ , and i saw other sources the answer is still coming to be $0.517$

Any ideas or help!

Comment: Your chart specifically says $f(0.562)<0$, which is why it is used as the new right endpoint in step 5, with the left endpoint still being 0.5. (since you haven't found another point with $f>0$ yet).

Comment: If you check by calculator $f(0.562) > 0$  and $f(0.625) < 0$?

Comment: >> cos(0.562)-0.562*exp(0.562)

ans =

   -0.1397 That said I technically misspoke: the chart says $f(0.5) f(0.562)<0$, but $f(0.5)>0$, so it therefore says $f(0.562)<0$ as I originally said.

Comment: Is the agument in cosine term radian or in degree ?

Comment: As when i use my fx-991MS it gives positive and when i google it , it gives me negative?

Comment: Google gives $\cos(0.562) = 0.84619104481$ , fx-991MS gives $\cos(0.562) = 0.999951894$...??

Comment: Barring additional context, you should generally assume trig functions are measured in radians.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, it seems you are using degrees instead of radians for cosine. Letting $\operatorname{cosd}$ be cosine in degrees and $\cos$ be cosine in radians, one has

$$\cos(0.562)\approx0.84619,\quad\operatorname{cosd}(0.562)\approx0.99995$$
$$\cos(0.562)-0.562e^{0.562}\approx-0.13966,\quad\operatorname{cosd}(0.562)-0.562e^{0.562}\approx0.01410$$